# Get an item in a list of taxonomy

Tags: routes, tokens

Hello Drupal Community,

I am creating a menu which has a link to an "editorial". I created a taxonomy named "edito" and created articles (content type) that are tagged with this taxonomy.

I need to recover the last article tagged with this taxonomy in the menu as a link (see image attached). Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this ?[image: link that needs to be changed]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to hard-code the URL to the item in the menu item edit screen.

You should add a [View](http://drupal.org/project/views) to your Menu.

Views allows you create a view including a filter to show only recent content.

[image]

You can then add a filter for a specific Content Type, User or whatever. And you can limit the View to show only `N items`.

You can insert the View of new items into your menu with the help of 3rd party modules, an example is [Menu Attach Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block), see the project page for a list of similar helper modules.

Comment: How can i add a view to a menu ? I know how to add a menu to a view but i've never done the opposite.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Creating a view that display the last content type with the taxonomy editorial and display it's link in the menu. Thanks, I think that'll work !